# Pass Parameters to Stored Function in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

This PostgreSQL COPY command works:

```
copy a from '/tmp/main.csv' WITH (FORMAT csv)
```

but I want the tablename and filepath to be dynamically generated. How can I do this?

I did try with following by calling the `select  import_csv('/tmp/main.csv','a');`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION import_csv(
    csv_path text,
    target_table text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
begin
    set schema 'public';
    raise notice 'CSV PATH: %,TABLE NAME: %',csv_path,target_table;
    execute format('copy %I from %I WITH (FORMAT csv)',target_table, csv_path);
    return;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION import_csv(text, text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I got Error:

> NOTICE:  CSV PATH: /tmp/main.csv,TABLE NAME: a
>
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""/tmp/main.csv""
>
> LINE 1: `copy a from "/tmp/main.csv" WITH (FORMAT csv)`

Answer (score 3):

change to:

```
execute format('copy %I from %L WITH (FORMAT csv)',target_table, csv_path);
```

%I quotes db object, while path is just a string

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html:

> The type of format conversion to use to produce the format specifier's
>   output. The following types are supported:
>
> s formats the argument value as a simple string. A null value is
>   treated as an empty string.
>
> I treats the argument value **as an SQL identifier**, double-quoting it if
>   necessary. It is an error for the value to be null (equivalent to
>   quote_ident).
>
> L quotes the argument value as an SQL literal. A null value is
>   displayed as the string NULL, without quotes (equivalent to
>   quote_nullable).
>
> In addition to the format specifiers described above, the special
>   sequence %% may be used to output a literal % character.

emphasis mine

Comment: Got thanks.how about for truncate the table just before the line execute format

Comment: @AjayTakur If I answered your question, could you please accept it?